# Reflector does not show casting operation

Tags: c#, casting, reflector

I have enumeration code below

```
public enum PermissionType
{
    X=1, 
    Y=2, 
    Z=3, 
}
```

I assign it to viewbag in MVC project to use in view

```
int permissionResult=2;
ViewBag.ContractType = (PermissionType)permissionResult;
```

but when I examine dll file with Telerik JustDecompile reflector, It does not show the casting operation? Would someone please explain why reflector does not show ?  reflector code block below

```
 ((dynamic)base.get_ViewBag()).ContractType = permissionResult;
```

thank you,

Comment: I would assume it's because the cast is not required so it is optimised away. What is the need to cast `PermissionType` to `PermissionType`?

Comment: but permission is integer. I am sorry, let me correct question

Comment: Well, I don't know much about how compilers do their business, but considering an enum is basically just a number anyway so it would still be logical for it to only want to store an `int` value. The more important question I think is why do you care? In your view you are going to have to re-cast anyway if you want to use it.

Comment: I just wonder, and learn it, if it because of compiler or reflector